# Unsupported - Tuple and Int

Tags: python, error-handling, unsupportedoperation

I've done a bit of research on this error but I still haven't been able to fix it. I've tried different syntax and codes. The error seems to be on lines mean_value= and std_value=.

```
# Moving Mean
for i in enumerate(inputs_filtered):
    mean_value = sum(inputs_filtered[i-smoothing:i])/smoothing

# Standard Deviation
for i in enumerate(inputs_filtered):
    std_value = math.sqrt(sum((inputs_filtered[i-smoothing:i])-mean_value)/smoothing)
```

Comment: Can you post the exception as well?

Comment: Hello @MenyIssakov What exactly is the exception? I'm still sort of new to python. Is this it? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that using `enumerate` on a list is returning a tuple and not just `i` as you expected, it returns the index, and the value of that index.

so in your case, `i` is a tuple, and you're trying to subtract `smoothing` off of a tuple

e.g:

```
for index, val in enumerate([10,20,30,40,50]):
    print(index, val)
0 10
1 20
2 30
3 40
4 50
```

If you need to iterate and fetch the value for every index, use:

```
for value in inputs_filtered:
    # do something...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm still unsure of what to do. I want to keep the [i-smoothing:i]. What do I change enumerate to for the code to work?

Comment: If your calculations doesn't need the indices, but need the actual values, just remove the `enumerate`

Comment: Ok thank you :D  I've managed to fix the tuple problem. Now I have another error for a different line: std_value = math.sqrt(sum((inputs_filtered[i-smoothing:i])-mean_value)/smoothing)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Comment: Your issue is here: inputs_filtered[i-smoothing:i]
If you'll add this line to your code (inside the for loop), you'll see that you get an empty list


        print(inputs_filtered[i-smoothing:i])

Comment: I see. I want that to work the same way as in the previous equation for mean value. So it'll sum all the values from i-smoothing to i. How do I approach this fix?

Comment: When I add the line 'print(inputs_filtered[i-smoothing:i])', I get nothing, not even a list

Comment: Can you update the code so I can see exactly what you did?